# How to create the sound of old antique style recordings?

Tags: sound-effects, noise, vintage, old, reamping

What are some other ways you all go about antiquing recordings?

Things I have been experimenting with

- Izotope vinyl
- boscomac The cornet reaktor ensemble
- flexing individual words in logic flex time set to speed
- the obvious hi/lo cut
- mild distortion

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [Speakerphone](https://www.audioease.com/Pages/Speakerphone/speakerphone.html)!

Other things:

- reamp through an old speaker
- reamp and record through a ribbon mic
- reamp through a [copperphone](http://www.placidaudio.com/the-copperphone/)
- convolution with samples of old devices
- overdo a tape emulator plugin
- overdo a console emulator plugin

Comment: Rene, I always go to convolution first for everything, i don't know how this escaped me. 

Answer (score 2):

In Protools, try the built in "Lofi" and "Vintage Filter" plugs as well...Oh and if you have Waves, check out the Kings Microphone plug-in. Fun if a little heavy handed.

Comment: What version of PT has a "Vintage Filter?"

Comment: It's the AIR Vintage Filter (RTAS only). They started shipping with PT8